# How to notate Gb7 with E natural and Eb?

Tags: musescore, enharmonics

I'm trying to notate a progression from the linked video using Musescore, and am confused by the Gb7...

I thought I understood the concept of enharmonics, but in this case, I'm not sure how to apply it!

Here's the fingering, and my attempt - I've added both flat and natural symbol from the accidentals palette, which doesn't seem right , but I'm unclear on the alternatives (surely I don't express the E natural as a Fb?!)

What is the clearest (widely understood) way to notate this, given that the progression is in Cm, but is not strictly diatonic (if I understand correctly)?

[image: Gb7 fingering]

(updated: added the second option as I understand it from comments)

[image: two attempts to notate]

#### Context

This clip plays the phrase, then follows with an explanation of instructor's way of playing the dominant / tritone sub:

https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/-Q0413UQjrs?start=268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To notate the chord in a strictly "correct" way, then the second option, containing Eb and Fb is the way to go. The Fb is the seventh of the Gb7 chord, and the Eb (and Ab) comes from the fourths-based voicing being taught in the video.

For readability, I think it's a toss-up. I might favor the first version, with both Eb and E-natural, because I can process it more quickly, but that's by no means a strong preference.

Regarding the chord name, keep in mind that the discussion regards voicings to use over a dominant seventh chord. So the chord symbol one would encounter in practice would be Gb7 even though the actual notes played in the voicing are, strictly speaking, Gb9(add13). So a way to interpret the video is "when one encounters a dominant seventh chord, you can play a 9(add13) chord instead, and here's the voicing to use."

Answer (score 4):

The chord G♭7 is made up from the notes G♭, B♭, D♭ and F♭. Consider G7 - G B D F, with all notes flattened. Job done!

Your A♭ (on top of my notes!) would make it G♭9, but both E♮ and E♭ won't be right.

Comment: Thanks @Tim - Well put - Gb9 does seem a more appropriate shorthand! I can't speak to the choice of notes, but am wondering how to notate what's in the linked video, which nevertheless has an E and an Eb  (_updating some typos in the question..._)

Comment: By the way, his Cdom7 chord seemed to end up re-voiced as C13 (no 11). With an odd explanation - 4ths rather than 3rds - which still gets there!

Comment: The most commonly used 13 guitar chord shape can be seen as a stack of fourths, and if you include the 11th on the 5th string, it's a complete stack of fourths, all six strings used. Like if you play diatonic quartal chords, that would be one of them. For a G13 chord the stack would be (from bottom to top) G C F B E A. The C is usually not played though. :)

Comment: @ptim Tim’s answer is that this E is in fact a misspelled Fb. Note that an E in Gb would be some sort of augmented sixth, but the Fb is simply the minor seventh.

Comment: Someone might insist on it "actually" being an E, because it "is" F's leading tone, which resolves upwards to F...

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - interesting point. But then the chord wouldn't be called Gb7, the tts, which will, by def., have Fb. A chord's a chord, rather than being influenced by what comes next. Or not? It may get spelt wrongly in some books (Levine..?) but that doesn't make it right, technically. I often come across wrongly spelt chords in bigband stuff - C7#9 with Eb, etc.

Comment: Theory i.e. how you talk about what you do in music, depends on perspective. If you see an E there for some reason, then IMO it should be OK to write it as an E. It's a person's subjective view and reasoning. Levine has his own perspectives, they just vary case by case. ;) If an "augmented sixth chord" is extended to a 13 chord, how are its notes spelled? If you press stop on the tape and we never get to hear what would have happened next - does it change what the correct spelling is? IMO demanding some particular perspective to be declared as the only "correct" one is not always helpful.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - taking things further, I wouldn't be happy seeing/reading/playing, say C7 written with A#. Maybe I rely too much on 'getting it right', but remember, in key E, being incapable of finding the chord written Abm! When seeing a white key E note on pno, I usually call it 'E', but am aware that sometimes it isn't, and those times will be key and harmony dependent. Although I do understand often stuff is written for convenience (or in ignorance).

Comment: On a melodic (single line) instrument, Fb resolving to F would be weird. On a chorded instrument (guitar, keyboard, etc...), F and Fb in the same chord would be weird. As a conductor looking at a score, I'd write in the chords I expect on, have a feel for the individual lines and not be too concerned that the E and Fb were both happening (in different lines). As a composer, I might want Fb to be a little flatter than E, but then I wouldn't use a tempered instrument for that. Write for your audience and embrace E#s and Fbs.

Comment: Great discussion, learning heaps, tx all! So, do I understand from your answer that in this context, spelling the pictured fingering would be: `Gb, Bb, Eb, Fb, Ab`? If so could you edit that in so I can accept, please?

Comment: @ptim -  that chord, whilst most likely having the notes you say, isn't really a tts. It lacks a 5th, but that's quite usual, but has 6th,(or 13th), 7th and 9th. Making it, as I said, a 13th (no 11).TTs only needs 3 and 7 to match the 7 and 3 of the V chotd. I suppose this does it, but it's confusing to most.

Comment: Thanks @Tim! I updated the my notation image - can you confirm that the fingering pictured should be spelled `Gb, Bb, Eb, Fb, Ab`, like the notation on the right of the beige image? "it's confusing to most" - hah! especially me.. love the sound, though!